# How does one use #pragma clang attribute push with C++ namespaces?

Tags: clang, clang++

LLVM's clang/clang++ allow you to [specify attributes for entire regions of code](https://releases.llvm.org/7.0.1/tools/clang/docs/LanguageExtensions.html?highlight=apply_to#specifying-an-attribute-for-multiple-declarations-pragma-clang-attribute). The syntax is as follows:

```cpp
    // the following works fine under clang:
    #pragma clang attribute push(__attribute__((target("sse4.2"))), apply_to=function)
    void f(){}
    #pragma clang attribute pop
```

In this example, the function `f` would be compiled with support for the SSE4.2 instruction set. This would apply to all functions between `attribute push` and `attribute pop`.

What if we add a namespace?

```cpp
    namespace joe {
    #pragma clang attribute push(__attribute__((target("sse4.2"))), apply_to=function)
    void g() {}
    #pragma clang attribute pop
    }
```

The it fails with `'error: expected unqualified-id'`. Apparently the keyword `attribute` is not expected by the compiler.

Given how common namespaces are, this issue is somewhat unexpected. Of course, one can avoid namespaces to work around the issue, but it is somewhat inelegant.

Is there a better workaround?

I have verified this issue with all recent LLVM clang++ compilers (up to 8.0).

[I have created a gist to illustrate the issue](https://gist.github.com/lemire/d442fb2a9763e53c44055c1d02a3378f).

Comment: Looks like a silly parser bug to me. The easiest thing may well just be to fix the C++ parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work in clang 9 (2019-09) but not before: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/okfDiS

Comment: As a workaround, we put the attribute push/pop [before/after the namespace](https://github.com/google/highway/blob/51dddb41f44f8ca1206ba3d260869368950f51eb/hwy/ops/set_macros-inl.h#L239]).